# TTS for Esperanto

Tags: pronunciation, technology

Does anyone know of a good text to speech service or program for Esperanto?

Have been fiddling with AWS Polly Polish, but it doesn't say *glaciaĵo* right and other such words

--

Note, access to AWS and Google Cloud is not an issue. I am a professional developer by trade and have active subscriptions to both already.

Comment: Is there any update on this initiative? Interested in where you ended up with TTS Esperanto

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Parol](https://parol.martinrue.com/). It also uses AWS Polly, but it first converts the text to Polish orthography as far as I understand. It pronounces *glaciaĵo* well. There is also an [API](https://github.com/martinrue/parol-api) and the [source code](https://github.com/martinrue/vocx) is available.

Comment: Yes, Parol fist makes such conversion, but the result sounds too Polish to my taste, YMMV. In order to embed the speech generator in your software you need an Amazon developer account, which may cost. An alternative is to use Martin Rue's idea of conversation and use [Google's speech generator](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/), which IMHO sounds better.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas could you explain more on Martin Rue's idea of conversion as applied to Google tts? Would you also choose the Google Polish voice to start? Also, if you have a working example, please share!

Comment: @ina, go to [Parol](https://parol.martinrue.com), click the gear symbol and you will see what changes Martin Rue makes. There are changes for individual letters (e.g. c to ts), for fragments (e.g. io to ijo) and for abbreviations (bv to bonvolu). There are also instructions how to pronounce numbers. I think, that if you do the same changes to a piece of text, but let Google to speak it out with a Polish voice, you get a better result. To compare take the [example text of Martin](https://martinrue.com/how-does-esperanto-sound/), do the conversion and let Google speak the text out.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t tried it but you could have a look at the Common Voice project by Mozilla:
[github.com/mozilla/TTS](https://github.com/mozilla/TTS#readme)

Comment: The nice thing about Common Voice is that ANYONE can contribute by simply recording some speech. You can contribute at https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/eo/speak

Answer (score 0):

There is a TTS voice for Esperanto called "olga yakovleva spomenka". Not the best in the world, but it is an option. I use it with balabolka. its part of RHVoice, You can search it in GitHub. https://github.com/RHVoice/RHVoice

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Is the "olga yakovleva spomenka" part of RHVoice? If you can, please [edit] your answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Esperanto teksto-al-parola sistemo](https://54696d21.github.io/esperantoTTS/)

Comment: Welcome to [Esperanto Language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/) at Stack Exchange, marcani! It is not considered good practice in Stack Exchange to provide one word answers. It seems that you are referring to some text-to-speech project at Github, so provide some info about it: how does it differ from the presented ones, what it is good at, what are its weaknesses etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1746)